# Django dynamic objectlist in for loop

Tags: python, django

I have a nested for loop in which the inner loop's object list is to filled in by the outerloop

Template

```
{% for currency in currencies %}
    {% for transaction in transactions_{{currency}} %}
        //content here
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

View.py

```
currencies = ['usd', 'inr']
context['currencies'] = currencies

for currency in currencies:
    context['transactions_'+currency] = access.listtransactions(self.request.user.username)
```

What i need is the inner loop to translate as follows

```
{% for currency in currencies %}
    // {{currency}} iterates to usd 
    {% for transaction in transactions_usd %}
```

currently i am receiving the following error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /transaction/

Could not parse the remainder: '{{currency}}' from 'transactions_rcv_{{currency}}'
```

Is there anything i missed or alternative function? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't use variable syntax in tags, why don't you expose a *dictionary* mapping currency to transactions instead?

Comment: Yeah, figured that out, started django only 2 months back, so still have to learn a lot. I figured out a way with template tags, will post the result soon.

Comment: Maybe you can look into [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup). I think it does what you're after.